# How do i store data into a MongoDb Database using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, database, mongodb

I am fairly new to MongoDB and i've got an issue on how to store data from an Array into a mongodb database? For some reason when i implement the following code i get a lot of errors.

```java
    private void storeData(String[] trainSeats, String[] customerName, String[] traincustomerSeats){

        MongoClient dbb = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        DB dbs = dbb.getDB("Train Customers and Seats");
        DBCollection coll1 = dbs.getCollection("CW1");
        DBCollection coll2 = dbs.getCollection("CW2");
        DBCollection coll3 = dbs.getCollection("CW3");

        BasicDBObject oneDoc = new BasicDBObject();
        for (int k = 1; k < trainSeats.length; k++){
            oneDoc.append(String.valueOf(k), trainSeats[k]);
        }
        coll1.insert(oneDoc);

        BasicDBObject twoDoc = new BasicDBObject();
        for(int k = 1; k < customerName.length; k++){
            twoDoc.append(String.valueOf(k), customerName[k]);
        }
        coll2.insert(twoDoc);

        BasicDBObject threeDoc = new BasicDBObject();
        for(int k = 1; k < traincustomerSeats.length; k++){
            threeDoc.append(String.valueOf(k), traincustomerSeats[k]);
        }
        coll3.insert(threeDoc);

        optionEnter(trainSeats,customerName,traincustomerSeats);
    }
```

Here are the errors i get when i run the above code:

[click to view the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr0D5.png)

[image]

Comment: Can you include the errors in your post?

Comment: If you have the option of using Spring Data, it makes life a lot easier.

Comment: [MongoDB Java Tutorials](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/tutorials/perform-write-operations/) have exaples to write data to the database.

Comment: @JDHernandez i added an image link on the post - those are the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your error log. You are getting this error because your database name **"Train Customers and Seats"** have lot of **spaces** **' '**, which is not allowed in the database name.

Rename your database to "Train_Customers_and_Seats" or "TrainCustomersAndSeats"